# Installing gradle 2.11 shows it as 1.10

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

I am trying to install Gradle on my ubuntu machine, but when I installed and tried to check its version it says 1.10 instead of 2.11

I installed using below command:

```
$  sudo apt-get install gradle
[sudo] password for ser: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gradle
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,554 B of archives.
After this operation, 26.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gradle.
(Reading database ... 880324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gradle_2.11-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gradle (2.11-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gradle (2.11-0ubuntu1) ...
```

But version says it is 1.10

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.55-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-77-generic amd64
```

How to fix this issue.

I tried to remove gradle and reinstall it, but same issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove gradle
```

Comment: Do you have gradle installed elsewhere by chance? What happens if you run `sudo apt-get remove gradle` and then `gradle -version`? You might consider your $PATH as well.

Comment: @EricWendelin Using `apt-get remove`, it removes the current version 2.11 which I installed. But when I run the command `gradle -version` I still see the version as `1.10`, I can see the gradle at `/usr/bin/gradle` so gradle is still there, but not in `$PATH` output

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Have a look at

`/usr/lib/gradle`

If you see multiple version folders, you have to remove every folder manually like

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gradle-1.10`

Then you can install gradle normally.